# Vertical Scrollbar color does not change

Tags: c#, winforms, vertical-scrolling, backcolor

I am a newbie in C sharp. I created a vertical scrollbar (VScrollBar). I wanted to change the color of the scrollbar's Backcolor. As it is inherited from Control, when i changed the color it does not take any effect.
In the InitializeComponents()->

```
this.vScrollBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar();
this.vScrollBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(472, -41);
this.vScrollBar1.Name = "vScrollBar1";
this.vScrollBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(17, 80);
this.vScrollBar1.TabIndex = 15;
this.panel1.Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
```

In the Constructor->

```
this.vScrollBar1.BackColor= Color.Black;     //<--here is the back color property
this.Invalidate();
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I Added the lines after initializecompotents()-> 1.vScrollBar.BackColor=Color.Black; 2.vScrollBar.Invalidate();

Comment: In the future write the code in the question. It will be easy for us to read it and you will be not down voted. Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: @mybirthname: Its my first post in stackoverflow. I don't know the customs. I will keep in mind your advice. Thank you. :)

Comment: If my answer is ok for you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Not as simple as you might think, sorry :(

**Where does the Backcolor property come from?**

You have to understand that System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar inherits from System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Control that got a Backcolor property.

**Why doesn't it work?**

The System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar is just a wrapper around the control provided by the Win32 API.
Changing the Scrollbar Backcolor is not included there.

**What to do?**

Basicly you have to inherit from System.Windows.Forms.Control and create your own scrollbar control.

**Articles:**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41869/Custom-Drawn-Scrollbar

Yep, that is totally a reason why people prefer WPF.

Comment: I totally agree with you that, people prefer WPF now a days. But, my question is now, if Button inherits from control and the backcolor is changeable, then why not scrollbar? And thank you for your link, i made simple scrollbar using paint on my own though.

Comment: Like any other control, you can handle the WM_CTLCOLOR message for the scrollbar control too. You can set the background color and it works - kind of. When the control draws the scrollbar components, it ignores the color set by the WM_CTLCOLOR handler and uses the system color instead.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer mentioning a custom ScrollBar control that supports custom background colors and themes https://stackoverflow.com/a/73613059/5514131