# Change the background color of a VscrollBar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to change the background color of a VscrollBar? The best approach I have consulted is http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624997/Enhanced-Scrollbar or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41869/Custom-Drawn-Scrollbar, but no exists BackColor property, and BackgroundImage not works.

I tried the simplest thing like:

```
public class ScrollBarEx : VScrollBar
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.BackColor = Color.Red;
        base.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

It does not work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822086/vertical-scrollbar-color-does-not-change

Comment: Max: Is the same, there is no way to change the background color

Answer (score 4):

I built my own custom ScrollBar control based on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41869/Custom-Drawn-Scrollbar.

My custom ScrollBar comes with ready-to-use themes (VS 2019 Dark and VS 2019 Light). You can change the control background color by modifying the field **_backColor** or you can expose this private field with a property to allow you to change the background color from the code.

I have modified the original control to get rid of the 3D colors and replaced them with flat colors

[image: Flat ScrollBar]

Complete Flat ScrollBar control code in VB.NET
https://gist.github.com/ahmedosama007/c1b0cd327d395a5698c1e17e96d0f8f9

Answer (score 1):

Not much new info, but: you **have to** play around with `Paint` event and do custom drawing of your scrollbar, here is another link with this solution (custom drawing through `Paint` event) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C